# Listview and imagelist

Tags: vb.net, image, listview, imagelist

I am trying to use the ListView (lvImage.View = View.Tile), but I can not get the Image. Maybe a classic problem, but in spite of what I can find on internet, I am stuck. This link did not help me as well: [MSDN ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx). I also tried to use the property ImageIndex of the ListViewItem, but without success.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub btnAddImage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddImage.Click
    ' Add an Image
    Dim myOpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    myOpenFileDialog.Title = "Image loading..."
    myOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = True
    If (myOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        If (myOpenFileDialog.FileNames IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To myOpenFileDialog.FileNames.Length - 1
                addImage(myOpenFileDialog.FileNames(i))
                iCounter = iCounter + 1
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub addImage(ByVal imageToLoad As String)
    'LISTBOX
    lstImageBox.BeginUpdate()
    myImageList.Add(New myImage(iCounter, imageToLoad, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imageToLoad), 300, 100, 180, 120, 0))
    lstImageBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imageToLoad))
    lstImageBox.EndUpdate()
    'LISTVIEW
    'lvImage.View = View.Tile
    Dim imageList As New ImageList()
    imageList.ImageSize = New Size(40, 40)
    imageList.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(imageToLoad))
    lvImage.LargeImageList = imageList
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imageToLoad))
    lvImage.Items.Add(item)
End Sub
```

The ListBox is working fine, but I would like to move on the ListView. No Image are display in my ListView, only the text is present and an empty space for the image.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks,

JLuc01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the problem.

I just need to move: Dim imageList As New ImageList() outside the Sub procedure.

I just need to think harder! Damn it!

Thanks,
JLuc01